# Why does the ALF in a current transformer increase with less load on the secondary side?

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, current-transformer

I am studying measuring transformers and I recently came across an expression that implies that the accuracy limit factor (ALF) of a protection class TI increases when the secondary load decreases (less impedance).

I am trying to understand this, since the ALF is correlated with the current at which the TI reaches magnetic core saturation, and the saturation in a transformer is correlated with the primary voltage and frequency applied to it. Then the load on the secondary side shouldn't impact (at least much) the resulting magnetic flux on the transformer. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Alien Life Form?

Comment: Accuracy limit factor (ALF)

Comment: Texas Instruments?

Comment: Current transformer, sorry i put it in another language...

Comment: The burden on the secondary totally affects the magnetization current in a CT: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/646310/why-are-smaller-ratio-current-transformers-physically-larger-than-bigger-ratio-c/646312#646312